# rerun all angular object directive (not only link function) on route change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

i created a directive that simply converts some div tags that is stored in .html to a single element. i noticed the directive only gets compiled on page reload, when the route is changed the directive doesnt get fired up, i am aware that you can use $routeChangeSucess or $scope.watch to detect a route change, but in my case am not using a link function in this directory, i only use a templateUrl. what is the best way to reload/rerun this directive on route change. here is my code below;

```
stockfront.factory('directiveConfig', function(){
factory = {};
factory.returnConfig = {
    scope : true,
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    templateUrl : "",
    template : "",
    transclude  : true,
    link  : "",
    combine: ""
};

return factory;
});

stockfront.directive("mainDiv", function(directiveConfig){

directiveConfig.returnConfig.templateUrl = "./template/mainDiv.html";

return directiveConfig.returnConfig;

});
```

this is what i tried @Valery Kozlov:

```
stockfront.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.routeChange = false;
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function() {
    // handle route changes
    $rootScope.routeChange = true;
    });
});
```

then in the html:

```
<main-div ng-if="$root.routeChange"><main-div>
```

Answer (score 0):

store somewhere in $rootScope stateTransition status and use following snippet:

```
<my-dir ng-if="!$root.transitionInProgress"></my-dir>
```

Answer (score 0):

i just realized what i did wrong after checking the code.... the returnConfig property of the factory is being overriden on routechange when another dirctory is fired. the solution was to declare the factory as an object then add the returnConfig as a prototype property which makes it unique an every directive instatiation

```
stockfront.factory('directiveConfig', function(){

//constructor
function directiveConfig(){

}

directiveConfig.prototype.returnConfig = function (){
    return {
        scope : true,
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        templateUrl : "",
        template : "",
        transclude  : true,
        link  : "",
        combine: ""
    };
};

return directiveConfig;
});


stockfront.directive("mainDiv", function(directiveConfig){
    var obj = new directiveConfig()
    var dirDefault = obj.returnConfig();
    dirDefault.templateUrl = "./template/mainDiv.html";

return dirDefault;

});
```